# Android Facebook SDK - Connect without login button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

In my application I use the Facebook login button for now. But in a certain usecase I need to make the application work without having the Login button ( user presses my own share button etc ).

Is there any way to create a session and request for permissions without the login button? Whatever I have tried until now returns a wrong session status.

Comment: If you want to request permissions, then you want login.

Comment: I want to login but without using the "Facebook login button". I want to use my own button that redirects me to Facebook for login.